# PowerShell and executable

Tags: powershell

Every time I run an application (.exe) in PowerShell, instead of executing it as it does with scripts, the program gets run in Command Prompt.

```
Invoke-Item MyProgram.exe
```

I thought PowerShell was supposed to replace the Command Prompt but instead PowerShell opens Command Prompt which then runs the program. Is there some way I can get PowerShell to completely replace the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from another question:

```
Start-Process .\MyProgram.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought PowerShell was supposed to replace the Command Prompt

It is, so why don't you just do `MyProgram.exe`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. If I try to run a command-line application in PowerShell it just starts Command Prompt and runs it there.

Comment: @user1338113 - How did you try to run? Did you just do `.\MyProgram.exe`? ( assuming that the exe is in your working directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, and in short, it will depend on the program because `Invoke-Item` uses the Windows default file association stuff by default.

I'm betting that using `& MyProgram.exe` instead of `Invoke-Item MyProgram.exe` will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Start-Process Program.exe -NoNewWindow